# How to post a file in grails

Tags: rest, grails, post

I am trying to use HTTP to POST a file to an outside API from within a grails service.  I've installed the rest plugin and I'm using code like the following:

```
def theFile = new File("/tmp/blah.txt")
def postBody = [myFile: theFile, foo:'bar']
withHttp(uri: "http://picard:8080/breeze/project/acceptFile") {
  def html = post(body: postBody, requestContentType: URLENC)
}
```

The post works, however, the 'myFile' param appears to be a string rather than an actual file.  I have not had any success trying to google for things like "how to post a file in grails" since most of the results end up dealing with handling an uploaded file from a form.

I think I'm using the right requestContentType, but I might have missed something in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

POSTing a file is not as simple as what you have included in your question (sadly). Also, it depends on what the API you are calling is expecting, e.g. some API expect files as base64 encoded text, while others accept them as mime-multipart.

Since you are using the rest plugin, as far as I can recall it uses the Apache HttpClient, I think [this link](http://radomirml.com/2009/02/13/file-upload-with-httpcomponents-successor-of-commons-httpclient) should provide enough info to get you started (assuming you are dealing with mime-multipart). It shouldn't be too hard to change it around to work with your API and perhaps make it a bit 'groovy-ier'